# ElasticSearch: query_string search with phrase against snowball filtered fields

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm doing a simple query_string query that looks like this:

```
"query_string" : {
    "default_operator" : "AND",
    "fields" : ["title^20","keywords^10","description^8","content^1","titles^6","highlights^4"],
    "query"  : "\"south west\""
}
```

However, the search is matching documents with the words "south" and "west" that are not necessarily adjecent, e.g. "We are seeing low flying buzzards in the *south* of england and also the *west*". **I would like it to only return results that match the exact phrase**, e.g. "We are seeing low flying buzzards in the *south west* of buckinghamshire".

The analyzer used for both search and indexing is the snowball analyzer and I am guessing that this may be the root of the issue, i.e. do phrase queries not work with the snowball analyzer?

Any ideas?

TIA

Dominic

Comment: I am having hard time reproducing the issue - https://gist.github.com/imotov/f6e47b06f4444d5003f0. Could you add a repro to your question?

Comment: Thanks for that, hopefully your gist will help me narrow down the issue. Will update with either repro or solution.

Comment: The issue was to do with the way my DSL was being serialized (quotes and escape characters were being double escaped). Apologies for the time wastage - I'll be sure to use plain CURL test cases in the future.

Answer (score 0):

User error. The DSL was being incorrectly serialized.